# Does not implement interface member MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I can't make the Post Action to work. It gives me error over :IAuthorService in Services:
This is my code below:

> 'AuthorService' does not implement intreface member 'IAuthorService.Post(AutthorViewModel)'.'IAuthorService.Post(AutthorViewModel)' cannot implement 'IAuthorService.Post(AutthorViewModel)' because it does not have the matching reurn type of 'AuthorViewModel'.

Author class:

```
namespace Entities
{
    public class Author
    {
        public Author()
        {
            Books = new List<Book>();
        }

        public int   ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public List<Book> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
namespace Interfaces.RepositoryIntefaces
{
    public interface IAuthorRepository
    {
        List<Author> GetAllFromRepo();
        void PostFromRepo(Author author);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
namespace Repositories
{
    public class AuthorRepository : IAuthorRepository
    {
        AppContext myDB = new AppContext();
        public List<Author> GetAllFromRepo()
        {
           return myDB.Authors.Include(a=> a.Books).ToList();
        }

        public void PostFromRepo(Author author)
        {
            myDB.Authors.Add(author);
            myDB.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Services:

```
namespace Services
{
    public class AuthorService : IAuthorService // here is the error
    {
        private  IAuthorRepository _AuthorRepository;

        public AuthorService(IAuthorRepository authorRepository)
        {
            _AuthorRepository = authorRepository;
        }
        public List<AuthorViewModel> GetAll()
        {
            List<Author> authors = _AuthorRepository.GetAllFromRepo();

            return authors.Select(x => new AuthorViewModel()
            {
                ID = x.ID,
                FirstName = x.FirstName,
                LastName = x.LastName,
                Books = x.Books.Select(g => new BookViewModel()
                {
                    ID = g.ID,
                    Name = g.Name
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }

        public void Post(AuthorViewModel author)
        {
            _AuthorRepository.PostFromRepo(new Author()
            {
                FirstName = author.FirstName,
                LastName = author.LastName,
                Books = new List<Book>()
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Author View Model:

```
namespace ViewModels
{
    public class AuthorViewModel
    {
        public AuthorViewModel()
        {
            Books = new List<BookViewModel>();  
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public List<BookViewModel> Books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controllers:

```
namespace WebApp.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IAuthorService _AuthorService;

        public HomeController(IAuthorService authorService)
        {
            _AuthorService = authorService;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<AuthorViewModel> Authors = _AuthorService.GetAll();
            return View(Authors.ToList());

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
           _AuthorService.Post(new AuthorViewModel() { FirstName = "Olivia", LastName = "Fox", Books = new List<BookViewModel>() });

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error i get in error list in VS2017:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0738  'AuthorService' does not implement interface member 'IAuthorService.Post(AuthorViewModel)'. 'AuthorService.Post(AuthorViewModel)' cannot implement 'IAuthorService.Post(AuthorViewModel)' because it does not have the matching return type of 'AuthorViewModel'.   Services    C:\Users\Jack\Desktop\WebApp Domasna 1.9\Services\AuthorService.cs  14  Active

the code for IAuthorService:

```
namespace Interfaces.ServiceInterfaces
{
    public interface IAuthorService
    {
        List<AuthorViewModel> GetAll();
        AuthorViewModel Post(AuthorViewModel author);
    }
}
```

Comment: `Cannot implement ... because it does not have the matching return type of ...` indicates return type of the method are mismatch between interface & class implementation. Check if the method is implemented properly.

Comment: Can you please post the code for `IAuthorService`? It seems that interface `IAuthorService` method signature vs `AuthorService` class are different.

Comment: I posted it. Sorry for forgetting to post that at start.

Comment: The error means exactly what it says. Your interface has a return type on `Post`. Your implementation doesn't.

Comment: the signatures are different!  `void` vs `AuthorViewModel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is straight forward. Your interface has return type of  `AuthorViewModel` while your class has return type of void.

Comment: Changing AuthorViewModel  to void in IAuthorService removed the error. The Create controller doesn't seem to work now but i guess that is another issue.